# How write + NSDictionary in file

Tags: iphone, file

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dicta = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]  init];

 [dicta writeToFile:[docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:foo] atomically:YES];
```

I know only how write

W+   ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about appending to a file. Usually, you would modify the NSMutableDictionary using code and then save the entire Dictionary to disk using the code you posted above.

Comment: So first i read file -> add old value to NSDictionary -> rewrite?

Comment: Correct. NSDictionary has a method initWithContentsOfFile: